# UUID on copied EBS snapshot

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, uuid

Is the UUID of a copied EBS snapshot different to the original?

In mounting an EBS volume via the fstab in an EC2 instance and if it's a copied snapshot, it appears to be the same UUID?

Is this correct? Is the UUID the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A EBS snapshot is a exact block-by-block copy of the original content at the time the snapshot is taken.

In other words, the filesystem UUID will remain the same.